# Can't change target in schema compare

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, database-schema

When I try to select Target (or select Source) in a schema compare I get a Microsoft .NET Framework error: "System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added." It doesn't matter if I use a saved schema compare or make a new one. This is only an issue in one of my solutions, one created by merging several projects into a single solution when we moved from TFS/TFVC to VSTS/Git. The full error is this:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareConnectionDialog.PopulateProjectCombos()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareConnectionDialog..ctor(Boolean isSource, ISchemaCompareParticipant participant)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareSourceTargetControl.CollectFromConnectionDialog(Boolean isSource)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareSourceTargetControl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<SetupComboBox>b__0(IImageComboBoxItem i)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.SchemaCompare2.UI.SchemaCompareSourceTargetControl.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectionChangeCommittedInternal(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that when I merged the projects two projects called "Database" were added. I renamed one and the problem went away.